# Application Loader 2.9 Distribution error

Tags: xcode5

I'm new to the development of iOS.
I already have some apps on the app store, and all did this with xcode 4.6.3 and application loader 2.8.
Now, I have been struggling to distribute an app to the app store with xcode 5 and application loader 2.9, and every time, whatever I do, I get the same error : ERROR ITMS-9000: "**This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include both armv7 and armv7s architectures." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)**.
Does someone know what to do?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Unplugging the iDevice and archiving again did the trick for me.

Comment: I second that, who would have thunk?

Comment: Thx quite easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check your build settings on the target. relevant keys should be "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures". Check that both have all those (armv7,armv7s &arm64) or select the standard settings.

What you did probably is enabling only arm64, that means your app would run only on iPhone 5s which is very bad...